# How can I add a badge to a standard UIButton?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, badge

Is it possible to add a standard-looking badge to a standard `UIButton`?

If it's not supported semi-natively, what would be the simplest way to achieve this?

Example image:

[image: An iPhone UI button]

Comment: For the record .. November 2013, thew freshest most recently supported package seems to be: https://github.com/jessesquires/JSCustomBadge it works perfectly with no problems.

Comment: Having just posted that comment, I realised JSCustomBadge appears to work in Xcode5, not Xcode4.  "CustomBadge" works perfectly in Xcode4 https://github.com/ckteebe/CustomBadge  TBC both seem to work perfectly in Xcode5.  Hope it helps someone.

Comment: I just released a CocoaPod written in swift for iOS 8 that provides this functionality pretty much out of the box. It's still pretty early in development but I'd love to hear some feedback. Check it out at [https://github.com/johncosch/TIPBadgeManager](https://github.com/johncosch/TIPBadgeManager)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Here's a VERY NICE class by Sascha Paulus called [CustomBadge](https://github.com/ckteebe/CustomBadge), that builds and renders custom badges using Core Graphics. They're just UIView subclasses, so you lay them out using their frame just like any other UIView subclass.

I've used this library many times and always been pleased with the results. Flexible, easy to use. Totally recommend it.

Comment: There is also a cocoa pod for Custom Badge - http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/CustomBadge/2.0/Classes/CustomBadge.html

Answer (score 7):

You can check for several options here: [CocoaControls Badges](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=badge)

Answer (score 3):

The class that Apple uses is `_UIBadgeView` (https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/_UIBadgeView.h), but of course, this class is private (note the underscore) and not documented.

Here's another class that implements this view with the same look and feel as Apple's while also allowing you to customize it: https://github.com/JaviSoto/JSBadgeView. The great thing about this one is that it lets you position the badge relative to another view automatically, in one of its corners.

Answer (score 2):

We have a badge view in Nimbus that's super easy to use and well documented:

[NimbusBadge](http://latest.docs.nimbuskit.info/NimbusBadge.html)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how this is done out of the box and I honestly doubt that Apple built that into the SDK.

Anyway, you could create a custom view with a button on it, add the background of the badge as a UIImageView and place a label on it to hold the badge count.

That's a quick solution, it might be better to create a custom subclass of `UIButton` and add your badge stuff as a subview

Comment: Do *not* subclass UIButton - it doesn't work well, i.e. you only have a convenience class method for construction. Also, no need for the "container" view for the button.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go a similar way as @Björn Kaiser: Use the button as you like it, and then add a custom view with that badge as a subview to it - I've done it and it works well.

As for the view, you can draw it as you like. You can draw it manually or use CoreAnimation and let it make the main part, i.e. `theBadge.layer.cornerRadius = ...;` to give it a round shape, draw the text/number in `drawRect:` or add it as a label etc.