# How to add Badges on UIBarbutton like UITabBarController?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uibutton, badge

I want to know how can i set a badge to UIButton like UITabBarController Badge?

Comment: See the answers to [this question][1] on SO


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722669/how-can-i-add-a-badge-to-a-standard-uibutton

Answer (score 0):

You just want to add a background image to a button

```
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"YourBadge.png"];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(200.0, 10.0, 20.0, 20.0); // or whatever dimensions you want
    [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MKNumberBadgeView](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/mknumberbadgeview).