# How can I create notifications on UIButton

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, notifications, uibutton

I am newbie at iOS programming. I want to put notifications on `UIbutton` (for example displaying the click count on top of its corner), shortly it informs some counting on `UIButton`.

Is it possible? Please give some ideas or some short code for how can I do it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722669/how-can-i-add-a-badge-to-a-standard-uibutton

Answer (score 0):

in the header file add

```
  {
  IBOutlet UIButton *counterbutton;
  }

  -(IBAction)pushed:(id)sender;
```

in the .m file
     int count;

```
 -(IBAction)pushed:(id)sender
 {
    count = count + 1;
    counterbutton.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"count is %i",count];
 }
```

In the interface builder connect the button to the view controller for both the IBAction and IBOutlet.

Answer (score 0):

Flex_Addicted share that link in my question i guess sharing in here more discernible. In that example shows exactly what i asked and it is really easy do just add h and m files in your project. [How can I add a badge to a standard UIButton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722669/how-can-i-add-a-badge-to-a-standard-uibutton)