# how to add badge to UIButton similar to Fab Apps and increment it when user clicks the button

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to add a message like badge to `UIButton` and how to increment the badge on click of `UIButton`. Someone could help me please. Now how to customize the shape similar to the badge having 36. What control are they using.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fab.com/id469422050?mt=8

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Badge having 36 is an UIView that is added. U can add UIImage that is having shape like background and update UILabel that is 36 now.

For badge on uibutton, Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722669/how-can-i-add-a-badge-to-a-standard-uibutton)