# CustomBadge rendering "grabage" around badge

Tags: ios, ios6

I am using the CustomBadge library discussed in this question: [How can I add a badge to a standard UIButton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722669/how-can-i-add-a-badge-to-a-standard-uibutton)

Here is my code:

```
CustomBadge* customBadge = 
    [CustomBadge customBadgeWithString:@"$2.99"
                       withStringColor:[UIColor whiteColor]
                        withInsetColor:[UIColor redColor]
                        withBadgeFrame:YES
                   withBadgeFrameColor:[UIColor whiteColor]
                             withScale:1.0
                           withShining:NO];
 customBadge.frame = CGRectMake(self.btnUpgrade.frame.size.width - customBadge.frame.size.width + 15, -15, customBadge.frame.size.width, customBadge.frame.size.height);

[self.btnUpgrade addSubview:customBadge];
```

I get what I'm expecting:

[image: CustomBadge]

I am using a NavigationController. When I segue into another ViewController and come back, my badge gets a "tail":

[image: Bad CustomBadge]

If I get rid of the customBadge.frame line, the badge renders correctly (at the wrong position though).

The code is executing on viewWillAppear:

Any clue what might be causing this?

The CustomBadge code is at: https://github.com/ckteebe/CustomBadge/blob/master/Classes/CustomBadge.m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like CustomBadge's drawRect uses a rect of a different size when I change the customBadge's frame in my code above. Maybe it has to do with clipToBounds vs maskToBounds.

I added this quick fix:

```
CustomBadge* customBadge = 
    [CustomBadge customBadgeWithString:@"$2.99"
                       withStringColor:[UIColor whiteColor]
                        withInsetColor:[UIColor redColor]
                        withBadgeFrame:YES
                   withBadgeFrameColor:[UIColor whiteColor]
                             withScale:1.0
                           withShining:NO];

    // copy the graphics of the badge into a UIImage
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(customBadge.bounds.size);
    [customBadge.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // position the UIImageView at the top right hand side of the button
    UIImageView* badgeHolder = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.btnUpgrade.frame.size.width - customBadge.frame.size.width + 15, -15, customBadge.frame.size.width, customBadge.frame.size.height)];

    // put the badge's image in a UIImageView
    [badgeHolder setImage:viewImage];

    [self.btnUpgrade addSubview:badgeHolder];
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is with paths. So, to resolve it I would:

- Check that you start path from the point you want and not from a random one. That means you need to call `CGContextMoveToPoint` before calling `CGContextBeginPath`
- Close (`CGContextClosePath`) each path before using it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :-) It looks like CustomBadge's drawRect has a rect of a different size when the NavigationController comes back. I  n order to solve the problem, I drew CustomBadge with no change in origin and copied it onto a UIImage*. I then changed the UIImage's position on the UIButton.