# Can I add an alerts indicator in menu strip specifically in c# windows form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I was wondering whether I can add an alerts indicator in my menu strip in windows form. For example, like on Facebook, they have an alerts feature for notifications
[image]

If I can do it in any way, I hope anyone can provide me with a guide on how should I put it in my menustrip, Thanks.

Comment: It is quite unlikely that a user expects a menustrip to show an alert.  You are not constrained by what a browser can do, consider NotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip()

Comment: Yeah, Windows Forms apps generally use status bars and notify icons (possibly with "balloon tips".  You might want to draw some alert somewhere on your Windows, but there's no control that will help you (that I know of).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to use the `StatusBar` control in `Winforms` rather than a menustrip.

[StatusBar Control Overview (Windows Forms)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/statusbar-control-overview-windows-forms)

[Add a badge to a WinForms control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756038/add-a-badge-to-a-c-sharp-winforms-control)

Comment: Sorry I was going to add this article as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756038/add-a-badge-to-a-c-sharp-winforms-control

Comment: thank you for this andrew, it helped me in understanding this kind of feature in windows form